# Network adaptor dies during large transfer

Tags: windows-7, network-adapter

My network adapter dies during large transfer.

I can reproduce this by transferring a video file, 500M+, from my desktop to my HTPC.  The transfer will run for a few seconds to a few minutes.  The time it takes seems to be proportional to the speed of the transfer.  Faster transfers will crash the interface faster than slower ones.

When the interface dies, all network traffic stops.  So I can't contact anything outside of my PC.  Attempting to reset the network device will hard-lock the PC.  At this point, I have to restart.

I'm running Windows 7 with a Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCT-E Gigabit adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

I had to change the speed from "Auto-Negotiation" to "100 MBps Full Duplex"